# What is the correct usage of "nobody" versus "anybody" in these examples?

Tags: word-usage

1. Can I say:

> **Nobody** saw me

*and*

> **Anyone** didn't see me

The second example:

> I said **nothing**

*and*

I didn't say **anything**

Are all these sentences correct?

2. So, we can always sat something in 2 ways? At first with **nobody/nothing** and then **anybody/anything**?
   Or are there things where we can't do like that?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but there's an important difference.

> - I said nothing
> - I didn't say anything
> - Nobody saw me
> - Anybody didn't see me

The "nothing/anything" examples work, and the "nobody/anybody" examples don't, but it's not because of a difference in the words. The difference is that, in the first two sentences, "nothing/anything" are the direct objects, and in the "nobody/anybody" sentences, they're the subjects. These would work:

> - I saw nobody
> - I didn't see anybody

(I'm aware this is an old question, but adding the answer for future usefulness.)

Answer (score 0):

"Anybody / anyone" and "nobody / no one" do **not** mean the same thing and are **not** interchangeable.

- **Nobody/no one** mean NO persons.
- **Anybody/anyone** mean ANY person.

"*Anybody can come to my party*" would mean your party is open to any person. *Everybody* can come.

"*Nobody can come to my party*" would mean that no person can come to your party. There will be no guests at all. Not much of a party, really.

---

Your example does not work with "anybody", because "anybody" is a non-specific person. You can't say "anyone **was** there". Unlike the party invitation where "anybody *can* come", When speaking in the past tense you can be specific and say who, or who wasn't actually there. If there were no persons there then you should say "nobody was there".

You can use "anybody/anyone" in a negative way to mean nobody, for example:

> I **don't think** anybody saw me.

> I **didn't** see anyone.